# How to quickly determine Visual Studio 2010 Fonts & Colors Display Item name?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, colors, customization

Is there a hotkey or add-in/plugin that will allow me to place the cursor within text in Visual Studio 2010 and either take me to the actual "Display Item" or at least tell me what Display Items are "active" on that text?

Most of the time I have no clue what the Display Item name is that will change what I'm seeing in the editor.  I currently just look for the foreground and background color that I'm seeing in the editor as I cycle through the myriad Display Items.

I know it's wishful thinking, but it would make customizing colors and such SO much easier if I could go directly to the correct Display Item or at least see the name for the text where the cursor is located.

Comment: I REALLY hope someone knows the answer to this because i get frustrated with trying to change the colour settings every time i try.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm almost completely certain there isn't because I've been asking people about it since VS2010 came out. :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybee this can help the following code can be written on a click event or in a timer:

```
With RichTextBox28
.Find("YourText")
If .SelectedText = "YourText" Then .SelectionColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue
End With
```